# Haskell laziness and seq

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to understand laziness and `seq` in Haskell:

- in (1), is it correct that no evaluation of `v` occurs until the print in the base case requires `v`?
- in (2), is it correct that `v'` is evaluated before each recursive call, so that no evaluation of `v` is needed in the base case? If not, how do I implement this strict evaluation?
- are there any profiling tools I can use to confirm these two points for myself?

```
main = do
  f [1, 2, 3, 4] 0
  f' [1, 2, 3, 4] 0

g x = 42 * x -- this could be whatever

-- 1. lazy
f [] v = print v -- base case
f (x:xs) v = f xs v'
  where v' = v + g x

-- 2. strict
f' [] v = print v -- base case
f' (x:xs) v = seq v' f' xs v'
  where v' = v + g x
```

I know `foldl` and `foldl'` do what I want in these cases. I am more interested in understanding how this is implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

Operationally, in case 1, variable `v` is bound to a thunk, an unevaluated expression which becomes larger and larger until `print` forces its evaluation. The memory footprint is not constant.

In case 2, variable `v` is always bound to an evaluated number. The recursion runs in constant space.

By the way, it is idiomatic to write `seq v' f' xs v'` as

```
v' `seq` f' xs v'
```

(which is equivalent since application is always strict on the function) or, leveraging `$!`

```
f' xs $! v'
```

Another common choice is to use a bang pattern and forget `seq`

```
f' [] !v = print v -- base case
f' (x:xs) !v = f' xs v'
  where v' = v + g x
```

The bangs `!` ensure that `v` is demanded immediately, so even if it is a thunk, it is evaluated before proceeding. This also ensures a constant memory footprint.

As a profiling tool for strictness, you can try `Debug.Trace.trace`, which will print a debug message whenever some thunk is demanded. This is not to be used for general output, but for general debugging is fine.